# Waht could cause the eventlog service to consume memory?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-event-log

I'm running a bunch of Windows Server 2008 R2 on a 64 bits hardware. I recently noticed that the `eventlog` service is going wild about memory consumption. The service on its own can consume about 4GB of the available memory and is continuously growing.

I first took action to move `eventlog` in its own `svchost` process to confirm that it was the cause of memory consumption.

```
> sc config eventlog type= own
```

Then I cleared all the log files expecting to move away from a possible corruption.

```perl
> wevtutil el | Foreach-Object {wevtutil cl "$_"}
```

And restarted the service. However, memory consumption is quickly growing back to 3-4GB.

I'm out of clue on what could cause this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memory consuption was caused by one of our services monitoring the event logs. After having disabled this functionality everything was back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Possible causes:

1. A flood of events.
2. A corrupt event log

Your best bet is to clean up your event logs.
You can do this safely by [archiving](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749339.aspx) your event log or [clearing it.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3wah3h5(v=vs.85).aspx)
I was taught to then restart my server, however I'm not entirely sure how necessary this is.

If the issue recurs, go through your event log, taking special notice of the security log, to see if anything is causing an unwanted flood of events.